# Do I get penalized for hosting a blog in a subfolder?

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, blog

First of all, I know this is an ongoing debate, I’ve read forums and seen different opinions but I’m still confused. Here’s my problem.

I’ve started my website from scratch (design and code) and now after a couple of months I realized that it’s not very SEO friendly and my search traffic is close to none. As a result I decided to add a Wordpress blog to it as it’s SEO friendly out of the box and has some good plugins like Yoast.

My problem here is that I don’t want my current website to affect the blog section (get lower search results on the blog because my website is poorly optimized). On the other hand, I already have a couple of backlinks to my current website because I keep releasing design freebies and people share those (would those links benefit my blog?).

As I understood, if you make a blog on a subdomain, then google will treat it as a new website in which case the backlinks won’t help me. If I choose to go with a subfolder then I may benefit from the backlinks but wouldn’t I get penalized because of the existing website which is poorly optimized and maybe has a couple SEO issues that Google doesn’t like?

Comment: @john-conde Ok, now I can comment. The thread you marked as duplicate doesn't answer my question at all. I'm more concerned if I get penalized by google if I use subfolders. If you fully read my question I hope that you understand the issue here. Can you unmark this as duplicate so I can get answers to this question?

Comment: That question does answer your question. Google doesn't care if you use a subdomain or subdirectory. Also, it tells you that google does *not* consider a subdirectory as a new website. I suggest reading all of the answers in that question.

Comment: but wouldn't my current poor SEO affect the rankings of the new blog?

Comment: Just because your other pages don't rank well doesn't mean everything in your website will not as well. Each page is ranked on its own merit. If your blog content is good it can rank well. If it ins't, it won't.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess that answer my question in some way. Although I would've wanted to see more opinions on this subject.

Comment: As well, moving the blog to a sub-domain does not help your main site. It is just another site. You would have to rely on conversion tactics to get blog visitors to visit your other site more than converting blog users to visit pages on the same site.

Comment: @closetnoc Yeah, I got that but I what I was wondering was if a blog in subfolder would be penalized because the rest of the website is not that well optimized.

Comment: Not at all. It is like having many people rowing a boat, some will not row as hard as the rest. However, it is always best to update and make all pages perform as well as they can. It not always easy to find the time of course.